# Cannot upgrade or remove firebase from system

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I cannot, as the title suggests, upgrade or in any way remove the current version of firebase off my system and I don't understand why. I installed it using the firebase commands prompted when you first start a project, something in line with `npm install -g firebase-tools`. After I've installed other packages to go along with it and I've upgraded the packages accordingly.

Now I want to remove the package I just do not understand how to do it. I've run

`npm uninstall -g firebase-tools`

`npm uninstall -g firebase-admin`

`npm uninstall -g firebase-functions`

`npm uninstall -g firebase*`

...and many other variations. After a while of trying I just figured I'll check what packages may still be left.

`npm ls | grep firebase`

Shows no firebase packages are still installed, however, running any firebase command will still work perfectly. Running `firebase --version` I get `3.15.4`. I've also, just as a Hail Mary, tried running `apt remove --purge firebase*`

**Further digging** I figured that maybe the `npm ls` command was off, so I tried reinstalling all firebase packages. I ran it again and there they were, **however*** firebase was now at version `4.12.1`. Running `firebase --version` still produce `3.15.4`.

I'm really lost at this point. All help articles relating to uninstalling firebase leads to either how to delete projects or databases or to npm's how to uninstall a package website.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete it, because you need to remove entire folder. This worked for me when I ran into the same problem:

```
which firebase
```

This locates the folder where firebase is (in Mac case it's `/usr/local/bin/firebase`) and then you do:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/firebase
```

Now do firebase -V and you'll get `Command firebase not found`. And now you can install back firebase with the real latest actual version:

```
npm i -g firebase-tools@latest
```

However, if you run `firebase` it will still give you `Command firebase not found` for what you can do this:

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

Worked for me with almost exactly the same problem.

Hope this helps you too!

Answer (score 0):

try this link
https://firebase.tools/
command
curl -sL firebase.tools | uninstall=true bash