# Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-hosting

[Firebase Hosting Setup Complete, Error loading the Firebase SDK,check the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7PA4.png)

Got "Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console." message after successful deployment from Firebase. Read in another post that clearing the cache may help. However this did not turn out to be a solution for me. This error has occurred with multiple projects including blank ones. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Firebase. These are angular projects so I also tried uninstalling angular and angular/fire and reinstalling them both. I am currently using Linux mint Ubuntu. This is my first angular and Firebase project so excuse me if the answer is in front of me.

Comment: I had this problem.  first i forced it with "/index.html" and it worked then tried to figure out the problem.  in conclusion, i think we just had to wait a long time.

Answer (score 0):

[Cannot upgrade or remove firebase from system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894890/cannot-upgrade-or-remove-firebase-from-system)

trying uninstalling firebase with the first two commands in this post. `which firebase` then `rm /usr/local/bin/firebase`

then reinstall with: `curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash` or `npm install -g firebase-tools`

curl worked for me. hope this helps someone in the future because i just wasted three hours trying to fix it :')

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turns out that firebase is shipped by modules by default. To use the old regular javascript import, you can add `-compat` to the end of the javascript files like so:

```html
<!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.14.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.14.0/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.14.0/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.14.0/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this command when I served the project using

```
serve public
```

command. But when I used Firebase Serve command, the issue got resolved. SDK was correctly loaded

```
firebase serve --only hosting --port=5002
```

[Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6zqlD4_U3k)