# Can't deploy Firebase functions (Failed to fetch Run service undefined)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Can't deploy Firebase functions. I have two project aliases, it's working fine for the first project (dev), but not for the second (prod).
Whenever I write `firebase deploy --only functions` I get the following message

```
i deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
!  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions. Please upgrade 
using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
!  functions: Please note that there will be breaking changes when you upgrade.
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.prod.
!  functions: You are using an old version of firebase-functions SDK (3.15.7). Please update 
firebase-functions SDK to >=3.20.0
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged E:\FlutterProjects\pegasus\functions (218.61 KB) for uploading

Error: Failed to fetch Run service undefined
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I had the same issue and it was fixed for me when installed the latest firebase tools

npm install -g firebase-tools

Comment: This did the trick for me:

sudo npm install -g firebase-tools --force

Comment: If you've added firebase-tools to your ci/cd pipeline and it keeps failing with the same error, you just need to update the firebase-tools version being used in your pipeline. See https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase for more

Comment: If you are stuck on a lower version (I was stuck on 11.1.0) then follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046980/16653398 to get to 11.18.0

Answer (score 8):

This was also fixed automatically by upgrading the version of firebase-tools using the command `npm install -g firebase-tools.`

You can add the --force flag if you encounter the below error

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/firebase
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/firebase
```

Answer (score 5):

You may also need to re-source your terminal. I checked my version after `npm i -g firebase-tools` and it still wasn't 11.18.0 but did a `source ~/.zshrc` and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Or source ~/.bashrc depending upon your environment. Or simply close the terminal and reopen before attempting firebase deploy after updating firebase-tools.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your firebase-tools. Run npm install -g firebase-tools.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using Firebase Tools with a version that is less than or equal to `v11.18.0`, you might encounter the following error:

> Error: Failed to fetch Run service undefined

The first thing that you should take into consideration is to update to a version that is newer than or equal to `v11.18.0`. By the time I'm answering this question, [the latest version is `11.20.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools).

Furthermore, install the latest Firebase tools by using the following line of code in your terminal:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools --force
npm audit fix
```

P.S. It's also recommended to update Firebase Function to the [latest available version which now it's `4.1.1`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-functions).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you execute `npm install -g firebase-tools` in the functions folder.

Comment: This installs the dependency globaly, not in the functions folder.